# Cannot fetch a one to one child using hbm.xml configuration

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I've two tables, one is User and another one is Employee

User:

```
public class User {

    private int id;

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    private Employee employee;

    // Getter and setter
}
```

User.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.site.dto.User" table="user">

        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="userName" type="string">
            <column name="user_name" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>

        <one-to-one name="employee" class="com.site.dto.Employee" fetch="join" cascade="all"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private User user;

    // Getter and setter

}
```

Employee.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.site.dto.Employee" table="employee">

        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>

        // I'm enforcing the many-to-one to one-to-one by adding unique="true"
        <many-to-one name="user" column="user_id" class="com.site.dto.User" not-null="true" unique="true" fetch="join" cascade="all"/>      
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now after logging in, I'm fetching the User table

```
User user = userService.getCredentials(sessionDetails.getLoginUserName());
Employee employee = user.getEmployee();
```

DaoImpl code:

```
@Transactional
public User getCredentials(String userName) {
    Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userName));
    return (User) cr.uniqueResult();
}
```

For verification, I tried `System.out.println(employee.getId());` , but it was returning null. Infact, not directly as null, as Null Pointer exception which means it's null. I tried changing the fetch types, but I can't get the employee object. To verify further I'm atleast getting the user object, I get the expected user Id when `sysout user.getId();`

Yesterday I was having all the mapping in hibernate annotation instead of hbm.xml. At that time I've put @One-to-One annotation for both User and Employee and it was working successfully. But today I've changed everything to hbm.xml, and the problem occurs.

Comment: Have you verified that there actually is an employee referenced to your testuser in your database?

Comment: @Jack Yes I can confirm that Employee table data is having the exact user's id as foreign key.. For reference, I've added the DaoImpl code.. Yesterday it was working when I put One-to-One annotation in model instead of hbm.xml in both User and Employee. I doubt this problem maybe due to one-to-one in User and many-to-one in Employee in hbm.xml